# PHP/MYSQL Recommend/Unrecommend button with incrementation

Tags: php, mysql, button

I want to make a recommend button for the logged user to recommend a dynamic page of a product after he registered. First he will see the recommend button - press it - after that the button will turn into unrecommend and the after the button the other users will see the total number of recommandations. If the same user press again the unrecommend button the numer of recommandations will decrement.

Do you please have some ideas or examples in how can i achive that? Thank you so much.

Comment: Stack Overflow is for specific issues

Comment: Do you have a specific coding problem? People wont do the work for you here

Comment: yes but i need some suggestions because that is the issue :(.

Comment: i don't need the people to do the work for me i need to understand how to do the logic behind it.

Comment: This looks like a case for javascript/ajax if you want to dynamically add items without reloading the page

Comment: Create a database table named `recommendations` that contains foreign keys into the user and product tables: when a particular user recommends a product, the relevant record is inserted into that table; when they unrecommend, that record is deleted.  The number of recommendations for a product can be obtained by filtering and counting; and determining whether the user has currently recommended can be determined with a simple search on both FKs.

Comment: There are hundreds of like/unlike button questions here on SO - http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+like+unlike+button. In this current format, this question is way too broad.

Comment: You need a table with the recomendations, from where you can query what products has been recommended by what user. For each product you can query the table to see if it is recommended by the current user. That determinates if the button should show "Recommend" or "Unrecommend". You can also query the number of products that has been recommended by the same user (optimization of this may involve another table and using triggers to update it). The "dynamic" part means that you will be doing a lot of this over ajax. You need PHP code that will handle those requests and do the appropiate queries.

Comment: @eggyal Ok. Got it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For recommend action, you've to:

1. make a layout for the view of your product.
2. Use jQuery for changing button text (Recommend/Unrecommend) and controlling links for that.
3. A php server-side code, to add a recommendation entry with user_id and product_id to your database table to hold recommendations.

   `<button id="r_action" data-flag="0">Reccomend</button>
   ....
   ....
   $("#r_action").on('click',function(){
    if($(this).data('flag)==0){
     // Reccomend
     } 
     else{
     // Unreccomend
     }
   });
   ....`

By using jQuery post, you can post it to php, and there you can insert it to db.

For displaying recommendations count to other user, you can get counts using sql. If you want those counts instantly, you can use pull requests.

Same way you've to do to decrement the count by deleting that entry.